# Back to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have **MainActivity** with **NavigationDrawer** and 3 **Fragments**. I replace 3rd **fragment** with 4th **Fragment**. There is no **NavigationDrawer** and no **Hamburget button**, but the is a **back arrow button**. When I press **back arrow button** or onBackPressed I want to replace/return to 3rd Fragment. I have this code, but It's not work. Replace 3rd and 4th **Fragments**:

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {    


                MainActivity.toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

                FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                addFilterFrag = new AddFilterFrag();

                ftrans.replace(R.id.content_frame, addFilterFrag);
                ftrans.addToBackStack(null);
                ftrans.commit();

            }
        });
```

In onCreate 4th fragment:

```
MainActivity.drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

In onCreateView:

```
MainActivity.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_icon);
            MainActivity.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {

                    MainActivity.toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

                    FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    filterFrag = new FilterFrag();
                    ftrans.replace(R.id.content_frame, filterFrag);

MainActivity.drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                    ftrans.commit();
                }});
```

**UPDATE:** When I go back to 3rd fragment, Hamburget button works like a icon from 4th fragment`s tool bar i.e. when I click it always show 3nd Fragment..

Comment: You put your 4th fragment on the stack, so you could just call getFragmentManager().popBackStack(). Can you tell us what exactly is not working? Also, to handle clicks on the hamburger button or back arrow button you should use the onMenuOptionClicked.

Comment: Updated about ur question. 
I know about onMenuOptionClicked, but I cant show back arrow button in 4th Fragments ToolBar...

Comment: I think your problem is that the Drawer toggle has hijacked the toolbar's hamburger button to do its thing. Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but it may make your life easier to move fragment 4 to a new Activity so you can customize your action bar there, then when you return to fragment 3 you simply finish the activity that holds fragment 4.